# Android Studio: ZipException duplicate entry custom class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Android Studio main project uses two library projects (let's call it A and B). both A and B use my custom library (let's call C).

Upon compiling the main project, I got the following error:

*Error:Execution failed for task 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: **java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry**: com/mycompany/Tracking.class*

How can I exclude the offending class so that it does not get included more than once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is the same class `Tracking.class` in both dependence libraries.
This errors usually occurs when importing .jar files.
Firstly, try to remove this in your `build.gradle`.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

If it does not work, you should exclude the common module in one of these two libraries:

```
compile (A or B) {
    exclude module: C
}
```

Please provide details of your `build.gradle` file if these above solution does not work.